# Not found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. flask problem

Tags: python, flask

I have a code like this:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)
app.run(port=5000)

clients = [
    {
      'imie': 'Jan',
      'nazwisko': 'Kowalski',
      'produkt': 'Karta podarunkowa Media Expert',
      'wartość': 100,
      'ilość': 2,
    }
]


@app.route('/')
def get_clients():
    return jsonify({'clients': clients})
```

The problem is that while running the code ang going to main page: `http://127.0.0.1:5000`, I got an error:

*Not found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.*

In console I can see 404 error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2022 16:46:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I'm using PyCharm IDE, hope that's not the case. I shut down every Python process using `CTRL + ALT + Delete`. But it haven't helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is very simple, you must run your app after you define routes. Like this:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)


clients = [
    {
      'imie': 'Jan',
      'nazwisko': 'Kowalski',
      'produkt': 'Karta podarunkowa Media Expert',
      'wartość': 100,
      'ilość': 2,
    }
]


@app.route('/')
def get_clients():
    return jsonify({'clients': clients})

app.run(port=5000)
```

Modify your code and it should be fine